# JavaScript - elegant way to find last part "foo[biz][bar]"

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have an input with a name `"foo[biz][bar]"`. What is the elegant way to get the last part, i.e. `"bar"`? I can use jQuery and lodash libraries.

Comment: `"foo[biz][bar]".split('[').pop().slice(0,-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as @loretoparisi but overwriting the group.

```js
str = "foo[biz][bar]"
matches = /(?:\[(\w+)\])+/g.exec(str)
console.log(matches.pop())
```

Answer (score 5):

Yo can use the regex `/\[(.*?)\]/g` to get all matches between brackets, and then take the last match if any:

```js
str = "foo[biz][bar]"
matches = str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g)
if (matches.length) console.log(matches[matches.length - 1])
// based on answer above group override but without `(?:` non capturing group
console.log( /(\[(\w+)\])+/g.exec(str).pop() )
```

Regex `/\[(.*?)\]/g` explanation:
[image]

Regex `/(\[(\w+)\])+/g` explanation:[image]

created by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: Could you explain how does the pattern work? I understand why I get `"[biz][bar]"` when the pattern is `/\[(.*)\]/g`. What does the `?` do in `/\[(.*?)\]/g` that it splits the previous result to two parts? The `?` means "zero or one" of what?

Comment: I have added an explanation as well.